# google app engine won't recognize contents of php.ini

Tags: php, google-app-engine, curl

I'm trying to use curl in the google app engine, but it gives this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function curl_init()
HP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/curl.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/curl.so: cann
ot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
ERROR:root:php failure (255)
```

I searched, and found that the curl is disabled, and that i had to create a php.ini file with this code inside:

```
extension = "curl.so"
```

[image: image of where the files are and the curl code]

[image]
I also read that it could be a problem of versions of the service, so i did it in the getting started of the app engine(first version).but it did not work.

But it seems that the php.ini is not recognized by the app engine,someone could help me how could i POST using curl or another way

Comment: Please edit your question and post the code in the images as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things that you should also keep in mind:

1. cURL is only available for applications with billing enabled as stated in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/runtime#dynamically_loadable_extensions).
2. In your `php.ini` you have both `cURL` and `cURLite` enabled which is incorrect. Only one of those can be enabled and not both at the same time.

You can [deploy sample application](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/php55/http) following the steps provided, which will get you started using `cURL` with PHP in App Engine Standard.

For other methods of issuing `HTTP(S)` requests using PHP, refer to the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/issue-requests).

Comment: thanks for the reply, i checked if the billing was enabled  and i forgot to erase thr cURLite of the extensions when i posted the image it's my mistake, but i tried with just curl extension, and it still gave the same error.

Comment: Please deploy the [sample app](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/php55/http), following the steps provided and let us know if you are facing the issue there as well.

Comment: I gave up on the curl, and tried using HTTP(S)  request  that you mentioned and it worked .thanks for the answer.